# Ceiling options when junction boxes are present?

Tags: electrical

I know that traditional drop ceilings are an acceptable choice when junction boxes are present in the floor joists.  I was looking around at Home Depot for pricing and found this PVC system that allows for a flush mount type drop ceiling.  The tiles are removable, but it requires snapping out a couple of cross T's.  Is this specific ceiling still considered accessible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ceiling max website says the tiles are removable so yes the area is still accessible.